# How to make a cleaner copy out of a blurry text image before OCR?

Tags: image-processing

A [cleaner copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhtvY.jpg) can be obtained from a [blurry original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO30x.jpg) by using the `level adjustment` in *Photoshop* before going for a better OCR. The picture below shows an example. My code below failed to do so. What is the appropriate way to get the same job done in Mathematica?

[image]

```
 im = Import ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO30x.jpg"];
 Manipulate[
 adjIm = Dilation[Erosion[Sharpen[im, a], b], c],
 Grid[{
   {
    Control[{{a, 0, "Sharpen"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"} ],
    Control[{{b, -1, "Erosion"}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}  ],
    },
   {
    Control[{{c, -1, "Dilation"}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"} ],
    Button["OCR", Print[TextRecognize@adjIm]]
    }
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Level adjustments can be done with Mathematica using the `ImageAdjust` function.

But I think `Binarize`is good enough for the case you presented. The results are pretty close.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO30x.jpg"];
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhtvY.jpg"];
Grid[{{TextRecognize@Binarize[img, 0.38],
   TextRecognize@Binarize[img2]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using v10, it `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` may also be worth a check.

Comment: `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` is not really a good idea with such noisy data.

Comment: It does have parameters which you can adjust, though.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know you could set mean and standard diviation.

Answer (score 8):

The following isn't focused on the Text recognizing part (I'm stealing it from @paw's previous answer)  but on separating the ads' text.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO30x.jpg"];
ib = Binarize@img;
dsc = DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate@ib, 500];
sc = SelectComponents[ColorNegate@dsc, "Rectangularity", # > .9 &];

Column[TextRecognize /@ 
  ImageCrop /@ (ImageMultiply[Binarize[img, 0.38], #] & /@ 
     Image /@ (Table[Replace[#, a_ /; (a != i) -> 0, {2}], {i, Range@Max@#}] &@
        MorphologicalComponents@sc)), Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]